# Get current theme or child theme inside wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Is it possible to get the currently active theme or child theme from within wp-config.php?

I've tried using several functions like `get_current_theme()`, `get_template_directory()`, etc but they are all undefined at this point inside wp-config.php.

FYI - I need to get this info at the top of wp-config

EDIT:

I'm looking to do this because I want to switch databases based off the current selected theme.  This is for my local setup only.  I have 1 WP install and a different theme for each site I work on.

Currently to switch sites I'm working on I have to go in and switch the theme and then manually update the config to point to a different DB.  I'd like to automate the DB part.

Comment: Why would you need to do this exactly? If you can provide some context we may be able to provide more suitable alternatives.

Comment: I've added some more details, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it better. Since you want to use a single WP install to work on multiple sites, why not use [Multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) instead and save yourself from having to manually edit settings?

Comment: That is not an option, I need to mirror the setup of production sites and they are not using Multisite.

Comment: Well, WordPress stores info on the currently selected theme in the database. The database gets loaded _after_ wp-config.php loads IIRC. I guess you could, for example, try detecting the domain name in wp-config.php (assuming you're using a different local domain name per site via virtual hosts, eg. `some-site.local`, `some-other-site.local`, etc.) and load a specific database accordingly. Or just create separate WP installs per site haha.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was possible, I guess not.  The domain does not change so I can't latch onto that.  O-well, I will just manually swap the DBs I guess.  Thanks for the help.